# ValueError: X has 94698 features per sample; expecting 94686

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to call my fake news detector model in a different file. However, `model.predict(text)` always raises a `valueerror: x has 94698 per sample; expecting 94686`. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

main.py

```
class GetText(FlaskForm):
text = TextAreaField()


@app.route("/project-1/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def project1():
    form = GetText(request.form)
    prediction = "HELLO"
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        text = form.text.data
        value = call_project1(text)
        prediction = "Fake News" if value == 0 else "True News"
    return render_template("project1.html", form=form, result=prediction)
```

project1model.py

```
model = joblib.load("models/fakenews-detector.joblib")
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stopwords_eng = stopwords.words("english")
tfidf_vectorizer = joblib.load("models/fakenews-vectorizer.joblib")


def clean_data(text):
    text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)
    text = text.lower()
    token = text.split()
    token = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in token if not word in stopwords_eng]
    clean_news = " ".join(token)
    return clean_news


def call_project1(text):
    clean_text = clean_data(text)
    text_series = pd.DataFrame({"text": [clean_text]})
    tfidf_text = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(text_series.text)
    prediction = model.predict(tfidf_text)
    return prediction
```

Comment: The error says that the model was trained of an X which had 94686 features per sample but you are trying to predict on an X that has 94698 features per sample. Recheck your `TfidfVectorizer`.

Comment: I checked the original TfidfVectorizer and all the values that have used fit_transform or transform all have a shape of 94698.